# Angular.js, é MVC, MVVM ou MVP?

Tags: angularjs, mvc, mvvm

Sei que em projetos angular tem model, view e controller mas muitos falam que o angular.js é MVVM e outros falam que é MVP

Comment: Já li em alguns artigos na internet afirmando com certeza que Angular é MVC = Model View Confusion.

Comment: Sei que é muito dificil definir, ate mesmo que tanto no mvc e o mvvm tem model view e controller, mas como eu trabalho com angular fico envergonhado quando as pessoas me fazem essa pergunta...Apesar de tentar explicar passa a impressão que nao tenho ideia do que estou fazendo rsrs

Comment: O grande problema é que ela pode ser tanto um, como outro ou mais de um junto (a grosso modo falando). O próprio Angular define como MVW, então, é isso que devemos seguir como oficial. O que acaba sendo redundante. Por isso o MVC(confusion) =D Acho que isso vai depender muito mais de como você organiza seu trabalho do que o que o Framework é propriamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem muitas informações na internet sobre esse assunto e apesar de uma publicidade que a google faz sobre o seu padrão falando que é MVW, Model-View-Whatever em que eu conocordo com @CelsomTrindade o que acaba sendo uma resposta redundante.
Depois pesquisar muito sobre isso e ter obtido a experiecia que tenho e validando o meu conhecimento na documentação do angular em https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController
E seguindo o  stackoverflow sobre a tag angularjs em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info 
também tendo de base a w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/angular/

Afirmo que angularjs é MVC Model View Controller

Answer (score 0):

Angular js é baseado **MVW**

O padrão MVW na verdade não é um padrão, MVW, significa Model-View-Whatever, ou seja, tanto faz qual padrão você acha que vai programar em angularjs, não perca tempo, apenas faça.

[Fonte...](https://bognarjunior.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/angularjs-mvc-mvvm-mvp-ou-mvw/)