# O que significa o MVW do AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, terminologia

Quando se pequisa no Google sobre Angular, é retornado:

> *[AngularJS — Superheroic JavaScript MVW Framework](https://angularjs.org/)*

- Sei que *MVC* significa *Model-View-Controller* mas o que é o W do *MVW Framework*?
- Este é um novo padrão de arquitetura de software? Um novo design pattern?
- No que ele se diferencia do "tradicional" *MVC, MVVM, MVP*?

Comment: _Whatever_ [.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207611/18246)

Comment: Sérião. Só não vou responder a pergunta porque uma hora o OnoSendai vai aparecer aqui e dar uma resposta boa. Se ele não aparecer eu escrevo algo.

Comment: Realmente significa Whatever https://plus.google.com/+AngularJS/posts/aZNVhj355G2 , mas tb espero por uma resposta boa do OnoSendai

Comment: @jbueno Pode responder, estou em reuniao o dia todo 

Comment: De fato é isso mesmo rs, inclusive isso já foi respondido no [Stack Overflow inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329485/what-does-mvw-stand-for), referenciando o mesmo link passado pelo Jeferson. Eu até responderia, mas acho que seria falta de respeito com o @jbueno que comentou primeiro.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Já aviso que esse é um tema controverso que muitos desenvolvedores podem passar horas e horas debatendo e discutindo, mas vou tentar *sintetizar* um pouco as informações.

---

## MVW - Model View Whatever

O padrão MVW na verdade não é um padrão, MVW, significa *Model-View-Whatever*, ou seja, tanto faz qual padrão você acha que vai programar em AngularJS, não perca tempo, apenas faça. Simplesmente o que funcionar para você.

Por vários anos, o AngularJS estava mais próxima do MVC (ou melhor, uma das variantes do lado do cliente), mas ao longo do tempo e graças a muitas refatorações e melhorias de API, ela está mais próxima do MVVM - o objeto de *$ scope* pode ser considerado o View-Model que está sendo decorado por uma função que é chamada *Controller*.

[image: Representação do MVW]

## Diferenças entre os *design patterns*

**O padrão MVW na verdade não é um padrão, *MVW* significa *Model-View-Whatever*, ou seja, tanto faz, não perca tempo e fique discutindo sobre essas coisas absurdas MV*, apenas faça.

### MVC

- Model-View-Controller (MVC) é um padrão arquitetônico usado na engenharia de software em que o padrão isola a "lógica de domínio" (a lógica do aplicativo para o usuário) da interface do usuário (entrada e apresentação), permitindo o desenvolvimento independente, teste e manutenção de cada (separação de preocupações).

### MVP

- Model-view-presenter (MVP) é uma derivada do padrão de software *model-view-controller*, usado principalmente para construir interfaces de usuário. No MVP, o apresentador assume a funcionalidade do "middle-man" (correspondendo ao controller de aplicação no MVC). Além disso, a *view* é responsável por manipular os eventos da UI (como mouse down, key down, etc.), que costumava ser o trabalho do *controller*. Eventualmente, o model se torna estritamente um modelo de domínio.

### MVVM

- Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) é um padrão de design arquitetônico para implementação de interfaces de usuário. Seu foco principal é a separação de preocupação entre a *View* (UI) e o *Model* (Dados) usando uma camada intermediária chamada ViewModel para melhorar a capacidade de gerenciamento, escalabilidade e testabilidade.

## Comparação de Código

#### Com DOM

```
<input type='text' id='bind-input'>
<label id='bind-output'></label>
```

E o  JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var input = document.getElement('bind-input'),
      output = document.getElement('bind-output');

  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    output.innerText = input.value;
  });
});
```

Temos que explicar muito especificamente o que precisamos do navegador para fazer. Temos que usar o *listener* de certos eventos, certificar-se de que o DOM está carregado, acompanhar as ID's do nosso elemento, tudo para atualizar o *label* sempre que a entrada muda.

#### Com jQuery

```
<input type='text' id='bind-input'>
<label id='bind-output'></label>
```

E ainda precisamos de JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input = $('#bind-input'),
      $output = $('#bind-output');

  $input.on('change', function() {
    $output.html($input.value());
  });
});
```

Como você pode ver, isso é bastante semelhante à abordagem DOM. Nós precisamos explicar ao navegador exatamente o que queremos fazer.

#### Com Angular

```
<input type='text' ng-model='bound'>
<label ng-bind='bound'></label>
```

Nem precisamos escrever nenhum código para isso trabalhar com Angular.(Obviamente, precisamos de um *controller* vazio em algum lugar, mas você consegue entender a ideia).

A abordagem declarativa é principalmente uma maneira de abstrair os detalhes de implementação. As diretrizes angulares tornam muito fácil concluir esses comportamentos comuns em pequenos componentes reutilizáveis do que podem ser aplicados ao nosso HTML de forma declarativa.

## Conclusão

AngularJS dá muita flexibilidade para separar bem a lógica de apresentação da lógica de negócios e do estado da apresentação. Todas estas denominações na verdade apenas separam a parte lógica da parte visual, não importando qual seja. O AngularJS deixa isso bem explícito quando você cria um *controller* onde os dados serão tratados e o HTML com as diretivas onde os dados serão expostos.

## Relacionado

- [Angular.js, é MVC, MVVM ou MVP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194389/angular-js-%C3%A9-mvc-mvvm-ou-mvp)
- [Quais as principais diferenças entre jQuery e AngularJS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21482/quais-as-principais-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-jquery-e-angularjs)
- [O que é MVP e MVVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21539/o-que-%C3%A9-mvp-e-mvvm/21541)
- [Comparando JavaScript vs AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864588/comparing-javascript-vs-angularjs) <sup>en</sup>
- [Is AngularJS MVC? MVVM? MVWhatever?](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/angularjs-mvc-mvvm-mvwhatever/)
- Temos uma pergunta respondida [no nosso Grande Irmão SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329485/what-does-mvw-stand-for) sobre isso.

Acredito que deu para ter uma idéia =)